# ValueError: Columns must be same length as key

Tags: python, pandas, dummy-variable, one-hot-encoding

I have a problem running the code below.

data is my dataframe. X is the list of columns for train data. And L is a list of categorical features with numeric values.

I want to one hot encode my categorical features. So I do as follows. But a "ValueError: Columns must be same length as key" (for the last line) is thrown. And I still don't understand why after long research.

```
def turn_dummy(df, prop):
    dummies = pd.get_dummies(df[prop], prefix=prop, sparse=True)
    df.drop(prop, axis=1, inplace=True)
    return pd.concat([df, dummies], axis=1)

L = ['A', 'B', 'C']

for col in L:
    data_final[X] = turn_dummy(data_final[X], col)
```

Comment: What is `X` in this case?

Answer (score 4):

It appears that this is a problem of dimensionality. It would be like the following:

Say I have a `list` like so:

```
mylist = [0, 0, 0, 0]
```

It is of length 4. If I wanted to do 1:1 mapping of elements of a new list into that one:

```py
otherlist = ['a', 'b']

for i in range(len(mylist)):
    mylist[i] = otherlist[i]
```

Obviously this will throw an `IndexError`, because it's trying to get elements that `otherlist` just doesn't have

Much the same is occurring here. You are trying to insert a `string` (len=1) to a column of length n>1. Try:

```
data_final[X] = turn_dummy(data_final[X], L)
```

Assuming `len(L) = number_of_rows`